# Santander US - app

Tags: decompilation

I am trying to see the requests of santander us app, but the app in the emulator crashes on open, crashes when using frida, and crashes when I recompile it using apk tool. I also used uber apk signer. I am not trying to hack the app, just studying it and the possible security resourses it uses. Can some one help me please?

Comment: It uses certificate pinning, and akamai bmp

Comment: Better use a real phone for network analysis. Root it with Magisk and install Magisk Safety net module. Then try to start the app without network interception. Then you can try attaching with Frida and bypass certificate pinning.